# Restrict from address to the domain

Tags: civimail

Our site is using SparkPost for email delivery which restricts email sending if the domain is not registered with the account. Sometimes user try to setup mailing or reminders or Email-Activity with incorrect from address (yahoo or gmail) causing mailings to bounce or reminders not sent. Is there any way we can restrict the user to select correct from address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension called [Outbound Domain Enforcement for CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/extensions/outbound-domain-enforcement) from JMA Consulting. This extension filters the From Email Address options provided to users as they are about to send an email. Only ones that have the same domain as the System-generated Mail Settings From Email Address are exposed, with the others suppressed.

**Note:** This will work only for the single domain i.e, but spark post allows you to set up multiple domains as subaccounts sharing the same API key. So if your CiviCRM site is called [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) and you have two domains registered abc.com and xyz.com at spark post, when sending email from [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) it will allow mails to send from @abc.com but not from @xyz.com